# Unity: GameObject bug in rotation axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: bug pic]

In the GIF above I am moving the plane with the mouse up and down. Watch how when I rotate the plane on its Z axis the plane still moves up and down even if the plane is side ways now. That is my bug. Why is this happening? What is wrong with my code? I think I am using the global axis and not the gameobjects axis. How do I fix this please.

```
x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMouseSpeed * 0.02f;
y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMouseSpeed * 0.02f;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
    rotZ += Time.deltaTime * 50f;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
{
    rotZ -= Time.deltaTime * 50f;
}

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, rotZ);

planeBodyToMove.localRotation = rotation;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why this isn't what you expect. Please describe the outcome you are expecting to occur with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the `localRotation` is just the rotation in relation to the parent object.

> The rotation of the transform relative to the transform rotation of the parent.

Or in other words: The `localRotation` is not local to the object itself but rather a rotation in the local space of the **parent** (or Unity world space if there is no parent). It does not mean that you rotate around your local Y axis necessarily. It applies the rotations in the parent's local space in the order `Z`, `X`, `Y` .. that is why sometimes you actually don't note the difference until you rotate `Y`!

As you can see here the same thing happens also without your code by just doing the rotation via the Inspector

[image]

Or to demonstrate it a bit better lets see what happens if we rotate it the way you actually want it to rotate:

[image]

as you can see as soon as one axis already is rotated, changing another axis now changes all three rotation values.

---

#### Solution

So how to solve this?

Usually I'm to lazy to do `Quaternion` calculations myself → I let the `Transform` do this for me ^^

Instead of storing the expected rotation in fields and apply it everytime by converting it into a `Quaternion` you can directly use [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) which rotates the object actually using its own local axis:

```c#
// Just a question of taste but I would prefer to have
// values that belong together in one single struct instead of multiple fields
public Vector2 mouseSensitivity = Vector3.one;

private void Update()
{
    var xDif = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity.x;
    var yDif = - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity.y;

    var zDif = 0f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        zDif= Time.deltaTime * 50f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        zDif= -Time.deltaTime * 50f;
    }

    // Wihout the optional space parameter uses local space by default
    planeBodyToMove.Rotate(new Vector3(xDif, yDif, zDif));
}
```

As you can see now each rotation is actually applied in the plane's local axis:

[image]

Comment: I love your gifs! Great answer

Comment: @Ruzihm hehe thanks, great to hear that from the Quaternion master ;)